# rbind tbl and df gives errors with filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rbind

I am using `dplyr` and loving it, but found a strange behavior. I am cleaning some data from different sources and putting them together in a data frame. Part of it required more cleaning, done with `dplyr` and resulted in a `tbl` object. The other part was simpler, and I had a `data.frame` object. I `rbind` them together, and when I was doing analysis, trying to use `dplyr` filter function, it wouldn't work properly. Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   group = factor(rep(c("C", "G"), 5)),
   value = 1:10)
df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(group) #df1 is now tbl
df2 <- data.frame(
   group = factor(rep("G", 10)),
   value = 11:20)
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2) #df2 is data.frame
df3 %>% filter(group == "C") #returns filtered rows in df1 and all rows of df2
Source: local data frame [15 x 2]
Groups: group

  group value
1      C     1
2      C     3
3      C     5
4      C     7
5      C     9
6      G    11
7      G    12
8      G    13
9      G    14
10     G    15
11     G    16
12     G    17
13     G    18
14     G    19
15     G    20
```

If I do `df3[df3$group == "C", ]`, it works properly. Bug?

Comment: Try `df3 %>% ungroup() %>% filter(group=="C")` or `as.data.frame(df3) %>% filter(group=="C")`.

Comment: @akrun yep, both of these work!

Comment: `df3 <- rbind(d1, as.tbl(df2))` results in the same issue, so it's not about 'df2' being a data frame.

Comment: `df3 <- rbind(df2, df1)` (switch order) will work too. `rbind(df1, df2)` returns `grouped_dt` with mess up internal structure. Check `str(df3)`.

Comment: Looks like using `rbind_list` from dplyr instead of `rbind` works (results in a data.frame regardless of order).

Comment: Could someone please file a bug on the dplyr github repo? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, will file. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, the issue was open here: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/606

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use the group_by on df1, its structure changes and operations are performed on it group-wise. When you do the rbind

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

R tries to create df3 with the same structure as of the first aregument i.e. df1 but since df1 and df2 are different types of dataframes, when you apply the filter it is applied groupwose only on df1 and results in the erratic output.

if you check

```
df3<-rbind(df2,df1)
```

df3 is a normal dataframe without groups and gives correct output.

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the row 'df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(group) #df1 is now tbl'

if you want to change data.frame to tbl_df, you ought to use
`df1<-tbl_df(df1)`

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   group = factor(rep(c("C", "G"), 5)),
   value = 1:10)


 # df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(group) #df1 is now tbl
  #  df1<-tbl_df(df1) 
    df2 <- data.frame(
       group = factor(rep("G", 10)),
       value = 11:20)
    df3 <- rbind(df1, df2) #df2 is data.frame
    df3 %>% filter(group == "C") #returns filtered rows in df1 and all rows of df2
```